# I have problem with testing Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

This is my first time using Google Cloud Functions. And I have trouble with running the function. My code is like below.

```py
import json
def location_sort(request):
    request = json.dumps(request)
    location = json.loads(request)
    reverse_location = {v: k for k, v in location.items()}



    x = location.keys()
    harf_x = (float(max(x)) + float(min(x))) / 2 

    y_right = []
    y_left = []
    sorted_location = [] 


    for i in location:
        if float(i) < harf_x:
            y_left.append(location[i])
        else: 
            y_right.append(location[i])

    y_left.sort() 
    y_right.sort(reverse=True) 

    sorted_input = y_left + y_right 


    for i in sorted_input:
        sorted_location.append([reverse_location[i], i])

    return json.dumps(sorted_location)
```

And i put in Trigger

```
{"38:127":"127.012","37.128":"127.002"}
```

and the error shows up saying

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
Object of type LocalProxy is not JSON serializable
```

How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `request` object here corresponds to Flask's [`Request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request) object, which means that instead of trying to dump/load the `request` object itself, you can get the JSON from the request with:

```py
location = request.get_json()
```

More details here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json